# How to get Google Chrome to open PDFs in "fit to width" mode by default

Tags: google-chrome, pdf-reader

When opening a PDF in Chrome, it is not fit to width by default. To achieve this, one has to click on a button that appears in the lower right part of the screen twice.

Is there a way to avoid this? Perhaps an extension?

Comment: You might want to set up the pdf reader to those specs. Preferences / Options.

Answer (score 1):

Any web viewer such as Chrome will attempt to use the Adobe URL#fragments commands.

So as per other answer (with or without frame or embed or object ) when you add after the inline dis-position `#view=FitH` then it should have a Fit Horizontally.

**There is no assurance it works in all cases but will work in most.**

[image]

Here a TEST colours.PDF is 3 pixels wide called as an application in Chromelike MS Edge it tries to fill the width of the window.

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --app=file:///C:/Users/me/Downloads/colours.pdf#view=FitH
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I answered this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18478120/how-to-set-fit-width-when-embedding-pdf-in-chrome/71951975#71951975

It requires creating an iframe, so it may not be ideal, but my solution provides some reusable code that I use on my websites. HTH!